# How to enable killing Xorg with Ctrl+Alt+Backspace

Tags: xorg, keyboard-shortcuts, settings

I don't remember why they did this, but at one point X.org decided that disabling <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> to kill it was a good idea. I know there's a way to re-enable it but I don't remember how. Can someone refresh my memory?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Modify `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or a `.conf` file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` with the following. (note: it is ok if this is all you have in your xorg.conf as xorg will still auto-detect the rest (note: that is if auto-detect works for you without it))

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DontZap" "false"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "Keyboard Defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard "yes"
    Option          "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection
```

Comment: They seriously disabled this by default?  No wonder it hasn't been working!

Comment: yes and it happened like 5 years ago.

Comment: When you don't have to zap your xwindows very often, sometimes its easy to miss a change that happened 5 years ago...

Comment: @Redbeard eh... xorg (and drivers) and kwin have been doing enough screwing around that I occasionally have to do it, and half the time I find out it's been disabled and I haven't re-enabled since my last reinstall.

Comment: @gabe. It's disabled by default because it's a potential security risk. For example, say the user logs in to the bare shell, starts X with `startx`, does some work, then locks the screen with `xlock` and leaves. Anyone can come along, zap X and get access to the user's shell on the tty.

Comment: I think you can still do about the same thing with Alt-PrintScrn-K.

Comment: In some distributions (e.g. recent Fedoras) these kinds of additional settings should probably be placed in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` as a conf file, e.g. `10-enable-ctrl-alt-backspace`.

Comment: any of these files/dirs not found on my Ubuntu 20.10 system: `❱ ls /etc/X11/
app-defaults                      rgb.txt   Xresources        XvMCConfig
cursors                           xinit     Xsession          Xwrapper.config
default-display-manager           xkb       Xsession.d
default-display-manager.dpkg-tmp  Xreset    Xsession.options
fonts                             Xreset.d  xsm`

Answer (score 12):

The `DontZap` feature is no longer working for me on Fedora 16 and Ubuntu 11.10 (most recent releases as of November 2011), so I found an alternative.

According to the X11R7.5 release notes, it appears that this functionality has been migrated to a XKB configuration option, therefore DontZap no longer works. I can't tell if this is a detail of the Xorg implementation in Fedora and Ubuntu, or if this affects other distros as well.

From http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/RELNOTES.txt

> Terminate Server keystroke
>
> The Xorg server has previously allowed users to exit the server by    pressing the keys Control + Alt + Backspace. While this function
>   is still    enabled by default in this release, the keymap data
>   usually used with    Xorg, from the xkeyboard-config project, has been
>   modified to not map that    sequence by default, in order to reduce
>   the chance that inexperienced    users will accidentally destroy their
>   work.
>
> Users who wish to have this functionality available by default may    enable it via the XKB configuration option
>   “terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp”. For    instance, the setxkbmap command can
>   be used to enable this by running:
>
> ```
>        setxkbmap -option "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
> ```
>
> Many desktop environments include XKB configuration options in
>   their    preferences to enable this as well.

Comment: my answer still works as of 7.6

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I prefer this option because it allows users to enable this feature without being `root` or having to modify system-wide configuration files. This command worked for me in Fedora 22.

Comment: The only reason I disagree with this option, is you can't kill the login manager, and if your "boot" into your desktop environment gets stuck, you can't kill it there. I recently had this problem.

Answer (score 10):

In current Ubuntu releases, at least since 14.10, the keyboard-configuration package has an option to re-enable Zap:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Answer (score 9):

With debian or based on, you can add this option :

```
XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
```

to /etc/default/keyboard file

Comment: Activate it: `udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change`

Answer (score 4):

you can try following ( I have tried it on my Ubuntu) :

Add the following lines to your xorg.conf file, making sure that when you paste it, it is NOT using smart quotes.

`sudo gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```
Section "ServerFlags"
Option "DontZap" "false"
EndSection
```

you can also try dontzap tool

`sudo apt-get install dontzap`

Open Terminal and type to enable

`sudo dontzap --enable`

for disable

`sudo dontzap --disable`

Comment: I really wish they had never turned this off by default.

oh, and apt-get doesn't work on my system ;) apparently we haven't packaged dontzap either. oh well.

Comment: did you try first solution ?

Comment: `setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp`

by itself that didn't work :( apparently you need to do this too.

Comment: @Hermant of course but it seems to be only 1/2 of it. I actually have it working now... there's a way to configure the xsetkbd option in xorg.conf. like so `Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "Keyboard Defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard "yes"
    Option          "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection` there are several other places it could be done too.

Comment: It will be gr8 if you can put your solution as Answer. So that others facing same issue can get help :-).

Comment: @Hemant I did... I was giving you a chance to modify yours ;)

Comment: @xenoterracide: opps I missed it :-). thanks for chance.

Answer (score 1):

@xenoterracide's solution is ok if the `AutoAddDevice` option is enabled in the `ServerLayout` of your `xorg.conf`. If not (especially in multiseat X configurations), you need to insert the `XkbOptions` line into the `InputDevice` section describing your keyboard. For example:

```
Section "InputDevice"
  Identifier  "keyboard-vmware"
  Driver      "evdev"
  Option      "Device" "/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd"
  Option      "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

In RHEL 7.3, [xenoterracide's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445/239817) worked for me, with one tweak: the path to the config file is `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf`.