# Enable killing X.org with a custom key combination

Tags: xorg, keyboard-shortcuts, kill, settings

I've just read *[How to enable killing X.org with ctrl+alt+backspace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375/enable-kill-x-org-with-ctrlaltbackspace)* and am really happy, that <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>backspace</kbd> no longer kills my X-Server. However, I'd like to have a way to kill it. It just should be something more complicated than what I type by accident ten times a day.

**Is there a way to define an custom binding for the kill-command?**

I'd like to use <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>meta</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>backspace</kbd> or alike and from the line

```
 Option          "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
```

it's not obvious how to do it (unless it is `"terminate:ctrl_alt_meta_shift_bksp"` which doesn't seem to work).

Comment: may I know why would you want to do that?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds From time to time, some application eats the focus and hangs forever. Killing the X server sounds cleaner than pressing the power button. In no case it must happen with C-A-Backspace.

Answer (score 4):

`XkbOptions` refers to a rule defined in the XKB rules file, normally `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base`, which will look like:

```
terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp =   +terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)
```

That in turn picks up the definition from the terminate symbols file, normally `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/terminate`.   I'm not sure if you can just add more modifiers to the `type="CTRL+ALT"` line there or if there's limits on the type value.

Documentation on XKB customization can be found at http://www.x.org/wiki/XKB and may be able to help fill in some of the gaps in this answer.