# How can I kill Wayland with a shortcut like ctrl+alt+backspace for X.Org

Tags: wayland

[How to enable killing Xorg with Ctrl+Alt+Backspace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/375/29), how would I achieve the same thing with Wayland?

Comment: What compositor are you using?

Comment: @StephenKitt whatever gnome3/fedora uses by default, though there's every possibility I will later switch to a different DE. So it might be nice if answers were comprehensive (either in one or across the board) so that this becomes a 1 stop shop for answers.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it. Wayland isn't a process to be killed.

Comment: @Flimm wayland is a process that requires less permissions than X (generally) to be killed, because it doesn't have to be run as root.